# How to fetch TAMIL values in FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, tamil

I used `mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");` to fetch the `unicode(tamil)` values stored in my database. But the output is just like

Status: ?????

Is there any possible fpdf functions to fetch tamil values??

Comment: Have you did the [makefont](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/) ?

Comment: Ya I made it with TFPDF functions.

Comment: i have some doubt can u help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should [make your font](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/)

Do can do it by the following steps

**Step 1 :** Go to [makefont section](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/) of fpdf

**Step 2 :**  Upload the font you required (Your tamil font)

**Step 3 :**  Choose the Endocing and Upload, then it will generate a `.php` as `.z` file. Download it

**Step 4 :** Add those two to your font folder of your `font` inside your

**Step 5 :** Then add those fonts in your `.php` file where you include the fonts

i.e.,

```
$fpdf->AddFont('Tamil','','Tamil-Font.php');
$fpdf->SetFont('Tamil','',11);
```

Add these files to the following folder: fpdf/font (This is the default folder structure that you need to download in order for your fpdf to work)

**Alternative Method**

You can simply inlcude the font in your `font` folder and add these lines in your `.php` file (Make sure about the the path in your system, you should have .z files in this method too)

```
<?php
require('makefont/makefont.php');
MakeFont('c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\yourtamilfont.ttf','cp1252');
?>
```